# Struts 2 action result and Jquery POST

Tags: jquery, struts2

I want to know how can I handle errors using jquery $post from Struts2 action result.

For example in my strut2.xml I have handled the error using the following:

```
<action name="helloWorld" class="net.roseindia.Struts2HelloWorld">
   <result="success">/pages/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
   <result="error">/pages/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
</action>
```

In my jquery call, I have the following:

```
$.post("helloWorld", function(){

}).success(result){
    $("#div").html(result);
}).error(){
    alert("ERROR");  

};
```

Even if the result is equal to error, it always goes to success.

So how can I make the result="error" go to $.post error in my jquery call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is "success" because regardless of what "comes back" you will have an AJAX successful request/response. What you'll need to do is set some "failure" notice from the servlet and then examine what comes back in the "success" block.

"success" means the request returned a "2xx" code. "error" means a non-2xx success:

more on html codes here : http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html

So like something like this (**not useful code but you'll get the idea**)

```
$.post("helloWorld", function(){

}).success(result){
    if(result == some error condition) { this.error;} 
else { //process the success
        $("#div").html(result);
}
    }).error(){
    alert("ERROR");  

};
```

Edit: Below Anthony made a comment that since the user is in control of the service / page being requested - you can build the servlet / code in a way to return an html error code *rather than interrogating the resulted html* - this is a great suggestion. Thank you Anthony

Comment: "What you'll need to do is set some "failure" notice from the servlet and then examine what comes back in the "success" block." Why? I'd be extremely surprised if you couldn't return an error status code from Struts 2, and therefore cause the `.error()` callback function to be executed.

Comment: the result that goes back is an html page... so how can i catch this result == some error condition??

Comment: is it possible to compare the result with the page name returned? I am so confused

Comment: @ Anthony - Yes you are correct that this could be accomplished that way as well - I will annotate this into my answer, great suggestion

Comment: @ Newbie. So HTML response codes are what trigger success or failure. You have the option of either setting up your servlet to send a failure code in the response header OR you can send a failure message in the response html. In the latter situation you would still have a "success" in terms of html response codes, but you would need to interrogate the result and then determine if it is actually good or bad. Anthony's suggestion is the leanest, but if you are not able to modify your Struts servlet to do this, then you will need to examine the result & then determine if true "success or failure"